# Two pairs of projection operators of the Dirac equation

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, poincare-symmetry

The Dirac equation may be interpreted as the action of projection operator $\frac{1 - \Delta}{2}\Psi = 0$, where 
$$
\Delta = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \Delta_{b \dot {a}} \\ \Delta^{\dot {b}a}  & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \Delta_{b \dot {a}} = \frac{i}{m}p_{b \dot {a}}, \Delta_{b \dot {a}}\Delta^{\dot {a} c} = \delta^{c}_{b} \Rightarrow \Delta^{2} = 1.
$$
Here $\Delta_{a \dot {b}}$ changes dotted indice to undotted (transform $\left( \frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$ to $\left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right)$).

There is two projection operators $\frac{1 + \Delta }{2}, \quad \frac{1 - \Delta}{2}$, so $\frac{1 - \Delta}{2}\Psi = 0, \quad \frac{1 + \Delta }{2}\Psi = \Psi$, or vice versa. This operators leaves only two independent components of spinor $\Psi$, but formally it still refers to the direct sum of $\left( \frac{1}{2}, 0\right) + \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right)$.

There is another two projection operators $\frac{1 + \gamma^{5}}{2}, \quad \frac{1 - \gamma_{5}}{2}$, which also projects spinor on one of the subspaces. I don't understand fully what are the difference between these pairs of operators. Maybe, the first one leaves the spinor as the direct sum representation, and the second one leaves only one, $\left( \frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$ or $\left( \frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$?

Can you make understanding of it more clear?